# errors in concurrent programming erlang language by joe armstrong

Tags: erlang

The below code is found while iam reading the book ErlangProgramming Language by JoeArmstrong 
So please explain me

```
on_exit(Pid, Fun) -> 
  spawn(fun() ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    link(Pid),
    receive
      {'EXIT', Pid, Why} ->
        Fun(Why)
    end
  end).
```

Comment: Please indent your code and use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Did you read the explanation in the book? Which part did you struggle with?

Comment: Errors in concurrent programming language

Comment: Why do you think the code contains an error? Do you get an error message? Does the code compile but not work as expected?

Comment: no errors its a topic name

Comment: i have gone through that content but iam unable to get that one so please explain me @Marcelo Cantos

Comment: Frank when i was executing the code output is not shown and showing errors @Frank Schmitt

Comment: @user3382006 Would you then *please* add the errors you're getting to your question (and don't post them as a comment, but edit the original question instead)? (we don't have crystal balls here so we don't know what error messages your computer is throwing at you without you telling us).

Comment: You mean Joe Armstrong has made errors in his Erlang code? :O

Comment: no i didnt mean that @Chiron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of the chapter is *Errors in concurrent programming* and refers to how *error handling* is done in Erlang using concurrent programming (ie. linked processes, supervisors, signals etc.)

There is nothing wrong with the code. It's a demonstration of how one could handle a process that exits for some reason, by linking a new process to monitor the first process and trapping the exit signal of that first process in the second process.